# Python to Powerpoint: Export svg to a pptx file

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I was experimenting with the python-pptx library to automate the process of adding images to my presentations. I used code such as:

```
from pptx import Presentation
import os
 
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[8])
placeholder = slide.placeholders[1]
picture = placeholder.insert_picture('pie.png')
prs.save("ESEMPIO.pptx")
```

This works just fine, but it was noted that when zooming in the pie chart contained in pie.png becomes quite pixelated. Someone suggested to use SVG format, so I saved the image as an SVG (unfortunately, I can't seem to add the SVG file here). Now, if I try to do:

```
from pptx import Presentation
import os
 
prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[8])
placeholder = slide.placeholders[1]
picture = placeholder.insert_picture('pie.svg')
prs.save("ESEMPIO.pptx")
```

I get the following error: `UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f38da87c350>`, which I guess is because it does not like the SVG format. Is there any workaround to get an SVG into a PowerPoint presentation?

[PNG pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mle8P.png)

Answer (score 3):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/394) on the repository, svg support doesn't seem to be a priority for the devs, and they suggest manually converting to png and inserting that into your presentation. My best suggestion is converting to a relatively high resolution png so the pixelation is less noticeable.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, is there any way to save or convert a png to high resolution?

Comment: I think the `drawToFile` function accepts a `dpi` parameter to specify resolution.

Comment: Many thanks once again, that indeed does the trick

Answer (score 1):

A long-winded way to do this is to save your image as an emf (this involves calling Inkscape to do so but the process is explained quite well in this thread: [Convert SVG/PDF to EMF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367550/convert-svg-pdf-to-emf/59149291#59149291)) and then use this emf when you call `insert_picture`.
This image should render as a vectorized image in your powerpoint- meaning that it scales **and** remains editable (you'll need to right-click the image and select Group --> Ungroup if you want to edit).

Answer (score 0):

In md2pptx we automate the conversion of SVG to .PNG under the covers. It uses CairoSVG to do it.

md2pptx relies heavily on python-pptx to convert Markdown to .pptx.

You can get md2pptx here:

https://github.com/MartinPacker/md2pptx

Sorry if this seems like an advert. I just wanted you to know there is automation available.

Comment: Not at all, that sounds really useful, I will definitely give it a shot, thanks!