# How to export vector graphics to MS Powerpoint with editable text?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, powerpoint, vector-graphics

I plot graphs with Matplotlib in Python. When I save the plot as `.svg` and then import to MS Powerpoint, I can decompose the `.svg` into parts. However, I cant alter the axis annotation or plot title.
Is there a way to export a python plot to MS Powerpoint, so all embedded text is automatically recognized as textboxes in MS Powerpoint (so it is easy to change the text and alter the text size)?

Comment: Maybe this thread will lead somewhere > https://stackoverflow.com/q/71046000/3381305

Comment: Can you export as EMF rather than SVG?

Comment: will try both suggestions, thanks!

Comment: I tried both suggestions, but none was completely satisfying. 
So my best practice right now is to either make figures in Powerpoint in the first place, or to save the python plot as .svg, however, then a lot of manuell work has to be done for the plot to be easily editable.