# Batch conversion of PDF to EPS via command line

Tags: pdf, subprocess, inkscape, eps

I am trying to convert some figures from *.pdf to *.eps via Inkscape and Python. I resorted to the [Inkscape Manual](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html) and [Inkscape Wiki](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line) and came up with the code below. However when I run the script, no output is written into the working directory.

```py
import os 
import subprocess

# Change to working directory
os.chdir("C:/Users/Username/Figures")

# Iterate over all PDF figures
for figure in [i for i in os.listdir() if i[-4:]=='.pdf']:

    subprocess.run([
        "C:/Program Files/Inkscape/inkscape.exe",
        figure, # Input figure
        f"--export-filename={figure[:-4]}.eps", # Output figure
        "--batch-process"
        ])
```

There is also a [similar question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367550/convert-pdf-pdf-to-emf). However, if I replace *.emf with *.eps in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59149291/5696601) the files cannot be read by LaTeX.

---

Update: Inkscape version 0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)

Comment: Please include Inkscape version in your post.

Comment: Are you getting any errors at the command prompt? It runs fine for me but there are import popups for each file from Inkscape. I'm running Inkscape 1.1 on Windows 11.